# Colocar um delay em "this.form.submit()"?

Tags: javascript

Como colocar um `delay` no evento `this.form.submit()`?

```
onblur="this.form.submit()"

<input type="text" name="fornecedores" 
       onchange="this.form.submit()" autocomplete="false"  
       value="<?php echo $fornecedores?>" 
       class="fornecedores" placeholder="Fornecedores"  
/>
```

Comment: relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/execute-script-after-specific-delay-using-javascript

Comment: relacionado: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183872/put-a-delay-in-javascript

Comment: Ola Não tenho conhecimento de javascript não sei como adpita esse artigo a minhas questão

Comment: tenta  onblur="setTimeout(this.form.submit(), 3000)"

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres fazer? o que faz com que precises de um "delay"?